# Define bijection $Z^X \times Z^Y$ and $Z^{X \cup Y}$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I was given the following task

> Define bijection between $Z^{X \cup Y}$ and $Z^X \times Z^Y$, $X\cap Y = \emptyset$

I have the following proof

> We need to build a map $h$. Let's define it.
> $h(f)(a) = \begin{cases} z & a \in X \\ g & a \in Y \end{cases}$
> Now we have to proof injectivity and surjectivity. Let's begin with injectivity.
> Assume that $f \neq f'$. Then $\exists a$ such that $f(a) \neq f'(a)$. Therefore $h(f)(a) \neq h(f')(a)$.
> Now surjectivity. $\left.f\right\rvert_X = g$ and $\left.f\right\rvert_Y = z$

Could you please validate my proof ?

Comment: You posted this at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3832380/define-a-bijection-between-zx-times-zy-and-zx-cup-y already today.

Comment: You should define the map $h$ in another way, indeed $h(f)$
should not be a function but an ordered pair of functions. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\;X,\;Y\;$ and $\;Z\;$ be three non-empty sets such that $\;X\cap Y=\emptyset\;.$

The map $\;h:Z^{X\cup Y}\to Z^X\times Z^Y\;$ defined as

$h(f) = (f|_X,f|_Y)\in Z^X\times Z^Y\;$ for all $\;f\in Z^{X\cup Y}$

is injective and surjective.

**Proof of injectivity:**

If $\;h(f)=h(g)\;,\;$ then $\;f|_X=g|_X\;$ and $\;f|_Y=g|_Y\;,\;$ hence $\;f=g\;.$

**Proof of surjectivity:**

For any $\;(f_1,f_2)\in Z^X\times Z^Y\;$ there exists $\;f\in Z^{X\cup Y}\;$ such that $\;f(a)= \begin{cases} f_1(a) &\text{ if } a \in X \\ f_2(a) &\text{ if } a \in Y \end{cases}\;.$

Since $\;X\cap Y=\emptyset\;$ the function $\;f\;$ is well-defined, moreover it results that $\;h(f)=(f|_X,f|_Y)=(f_1,f_2)\;.$